# There is an error when importing data using the data table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

Use the data table to import data from the database.
However, if there is Hangul in the data, an error occurs. Why is that?

in this script code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var table = jQuery('#developers').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "load_data.php",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "aoColumns": [
            { mData: 'id' },
            { mData: 'name' },
            { mData: 'age' },
            { mData: 'gender' },
            { mData: 'address' },
            { mData: 'designation' },
            { mData: 'skills' }
        ]
    });
});
```

in this ajax load code

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");
$sql_query = "SELECT id, name, gender, skills, address, designation, age FROM developers LIMIT 20";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
$developers_record = array();
// echo $developers_record;
while( $developer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
    $developers_record[] = $developer;
}
$developer_data = array(
    "sEcho" => 1,
"iTotalRecords" => count($developers_record),
"iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($developers_record),
  "aaData"=>$developers_record);

echo json_encode($developer_data);



exit;
?>
```

If there is Korean in the data, the following error occurs:

[image]

how do fix in this error??

add result

If there is not Korean language in the data , it is marked as follows.

[image]

but If there is Korean language in the data, it is expressed as follows.
Nothing is marked.

Comment: can you provide the returned JSON?

Comment: @HagaiWild add json result

Comment: @HagaiWild I can solved it  add mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

Answer (score 1):

Change the single quotes to double quotes like this:

```
{
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "load_data.php",
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "aoColumns": [{
            "mData": "id"
        },
        {
            "mData": "name"
        },
        {
            "mData": "age"
        },
        {
            "mData": "gender"
        },
        {
            "mData": "address"
        },
        {
            "mData": "designation"
        },
        {
            "mData": "skills"
        }
    ]
}
```

It could be the problem. The json standard says: "A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array." Maybe it solves the problem.

Comment: Only this is not a JSON.. so your answer is invalid.

Comment: Yes, Adrian missed the second property names - but he had the right idea. A good trick is to paste any JSON into a decent text editor, and set the syntax to JSON - and then look for highlighted errors.

Comment: Thanks Dycey for your explanation!